# Poly-Markdown+R does not find the right version of R for R code chunks

Tags: ess, r, polymode

I am working on a Rmarkdown document and I have R 4.0.4 running in a buffer. I try to export the document with `M-n e` and it finds R 3.6.3

```
sessionInfo()
```

R version 3.6.3

This meant that I had a lot of trouble with packages not being found before I saw the underlying problem. I have a distribution R 3.6.3 in `/usr/bin` and a more recent R in `/use/local/bin`. poly-R may be using absolute path names but I can't see how to configure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polymode uses [ESS](https://ess.r-project.org/) to interact with R. Your locally-installed version of R in `/usr/local/bin` is probably not on the exec path. You can configure this via the variable `ess-rterm-version-paths`. You may also need to check the values in `ess-r-runner-prefixes` to make sure it includes `R-4`.

These configurations have changed in the past few years, so it will be helpful to know which version of Emacs, ESS and polymode you are using, and also your OS.